# Where is the tor log file

Tags: linux, log

On my linux i can run `sudo journalctl -u tor@default` to see tor log. where is the log file stored on the system. Maybe a unix.stakexchange kind of question but i opt to ask it here

Comment: Which distribution are you using?

Comment: @JensKubieziel kali-rolling

Answer (score 11):

By default `stdout` and `stderr` of a systemd unit are sent to **syslog**. On my machine(Kali distro) it is stored in `/var/log/syslog`. So to see tor unit output run

```
cat /var/log/syslog | grep tor -i
```

Or to keep following the log:

```
tail -F /var/log/syslog | grep tor -i
```

maybe you need a sudo:

```
sudo tail -F /var/log/syslog | grep tor -i
```

## Edit

In case someone needs to monitor tor unit i found a better way. Adding `-f` or `--follow` flag to `journalctl` makes it to continuously print new entries as they are appended to the journal. You can then pipe it to a parser and react based on it.

In one of your termianl tabs run

```
sudo journalctl -f -u tor@default | grep bootstrapped -i
```

in another tab do

```
sudo systemctl restart tor
```

You will see the results are appended to the first terminal as they are appended to the systemd journal

Answer (score 4):

Usually Tor stores its log files in `/var/log/tor`. Depending from the specific settings you'll find `/var/log/tor/notices.log`, `/var/log/tor/log`, `/var/log/tor/info.log`, etc.

The option `Log` in `torrc` specifies where the log file is stored and what kind of information is logged. So if you don't find the above mentioned files please have a look into your configuration.

An example entry could look like

```
Log info file /tmp/foo/bar.log
```

This would write a log file with `info` messages to `/tmp/foo/bar.log` .

Comment: Nothing exists in `/var/log/tor` and all options related to logging is commented out in my `/etc/tor/torrc` file. Still `journalctl` manages to show me tor logs. I guess it is related to how tor service is configured on the system than the tor configuration itself.

Comment: please mention the proper torrc logging synt@x? When i uncommented tor failed to start

Answer (score 2):

Usually Tor stores its log files in `/var/log/tor`. Depending from the specific settings you'll find `/var/log/tor/notices.log`, `/var/log/tor/log`, `/var/log/tor/info.log`, etc.  The option `Log` in torrc specifies where the log file is stored and what kind of information is logged. So if you don't find the above mentioned files please have a look into your configuration.

Comment: Usually Tor stores its log files in /var/log/tor. Depending from the specific settings you'll find /var/log/tor/notices.log, /var/log/tor/log, /var/log/tor/info.log, etc.

The option Log in torrc specifies where the log file is stored and what kind of information is logged. So if you don't find the above mentioned files please have a look into your configuration.